# VSCode .gitgnore not ignoring .sfdx folder

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, git

As in the title, I've encountered a problem with the .sfdx/ folder in my repo. After cloning the project it sees some local changes in the *typings/lwc* and *typings/tools* folder. *.sfdx/* folder is ofc in the .gitignore.

[image]

I can discard most of the changes except the *apex.db*. In this case I'm getting this error:
[image]

I've tried killing Java process in the background etc. but nothing worked. Only cloning project once again allowed me to change branches but this ofc isn't the solution.

Does anyone have an idea what's the issue and how to solve this one?

Comment: There may be a background process that is still using it, might want to restart vscode otherwise your computer as well and try again?

Comment: @Raul done that, sadly it's happening every time when the branch is changed so even killing the java process as this is the one in the background every time is not the best solution sadly

Comment: Have you tried soft reset in GIT? and also restarting your computer?

Comment: yes, all of it - nothing worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Try removing the cache for this file, it worked perfectly for me.

`git rm -r --cached .sfdx/tools/apex.db` or even just `git rm -r --cached .sfdx`

Comment: Awesome! `git rm -r --cached .sfdx` worked perfectly and everything seems to be fine now. Thanks a lot :)